# AngularJs 1.X custom directive in separated file is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, using-directives

Hi I'm trying to separate the code of a custom directive to manage checkboxes to a different file, but is not working and also it seems that is not loading when I debug with devtools I'm not able to see this new file.

**not.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var sn = angular.module('notApp');
    sn.controller('notController', ['$scope', '$window', '$timeout', 'dataContext', notController]);

    function notController($scope, $window, $timeout, dataContext) {
    }

    sn.directive('checkList', function () {
        return {

        };
    });

})();
```

**notApp.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('templates-notHtml', []); 
    angular.module('notApp', [
        'templates-notHtml'
    ]);
})();
```

**notDataContext.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var sn = angular.module('notApp');

    var dataContext = sn.service('dataContext', ['$http', '$window', '$rootScope', dataContextFunction]);

    function dataContextFunction($http, $window, $rootScope) {

        this.getPeriods = function () {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '..........'
            }).then(function (success) {
                return success;
            });
        };
    }
})();
```

**not.html**

```
<div ng-app="notApp">
    <div id="sn" data-ng-controller="notController" class="mainDiv">
    </div>
</div>

<script src="not.js"></script>
```

In this way the directive is working fine but when I separate the directive to another file, for example to customDirectives.js:

**customDirectives.js**

```
var sn = angular.module('notApp');

sn.directive('checkList', function () {
    return {}
};
});
```

and then adding the script reference of customDirectives.js in not.html like:

**not.html**

```
<div ng-app="notApp">
    <div id="sn" data-ng-controller="notController" class="mainDiv">
    </div>
</div>

<script src="not.js"></script>
<script src="customDirectives.js"></script>
```

Stops working by this way, and also I'm not able to see customDirectives.js loaded in Chrome.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: i don't see a script tag for `notApp.js` could it be that?

Comment: Nope, it's not that, it's currently there